# AngularJS: Load page on link click

Tags: angularjs, seo, angularjs-ng-include

I got 2 divs, first has links pointing to individual pages and another one to display the content of pages the links are pointing to. Here is how it looks:

```
<div id="navigation">
   <a href="http://mydomain/page1">
   <a href="http://mydomain/page2">
   <a href="http://mydomain/and-so-on">
</div>

<div id="content">
   <!-- display content here -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent redirecting the page on link click and display the content of the URL they point to? I'm doing it this way for SEO purposes so each individual pages can also be crawlable on their own.

I've heard of `ng-include` but I want to be sure I'm heading the right direction so I reckon I should ask first before going with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use an `iframe` and set the link's `href` as iframe's `src`.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer it the Angular way but I really do appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[AngularJS Routing](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)** for this purpose.

```
    <a href="#page1">
    <a href="#page2">
    <a href="#and-so-on">


    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("page1", {
            templateUrl : "http://yourDomain/page1.html"
        })
        .when("/page2", {
            templateUrl : "http://yourDomain/page2.html"
        })
        .when("/and-so-on", {
            templateUrl : "http://yourDomain/and-so-on.html"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

> **Note:** Must include [angular-route.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js)

Comment: Is it possible to use the full URL on the links instead? The page acts as a sitemap, if I may add.

Comment: No need to do that because you've mentioned the full URL in templateUrl